# Is there a way to use simply "android:" in attribute names with ElementTree?

Tags: android, python, attributes, android-manifest, elementtree

I'm parsing `AndroidManifest.xml` with Python's `ElementTree`. I needed to register the `android` namespace as `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` or ElementTree would replace it by something like `ns0`. It was unintuitive but now it works.

When accessing attributes of a node, I've expected to be able to specify simply eg. `elem.attrib["android:versionCode"]`. But it didn't work as ElementTree wants me to use it like this:

```
ET.register_namespace("android", "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android")

tree = ET.ElementTree()
tree.parse("AndroidManifest.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
root.attrib["{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}versionCode"] = "3"
```

even if in the file it was and will be `android:versionCode`.

As this is counter-intuitive, is there any way to use `root.attrib["android:versionCode"]` instead?

Answer (score 0):

No, there doesn't appear any other way to specify a 'qualified name' in ElementTree.

from http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm

> In an Element tree, qualified names are stored as universal names in Clark’s notation, which combines the URI and the local part into a single string, given as > “{uri}local”.
>
> "{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}a"
>
> "{http://effbot.org/namespace/letters}a"

Additional References

- http://effbot.org/zone/element-qnames.htm